# c++ the dynamic array of class allocation fails (memory leak)

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

edit1: add a running tiny version.
I wrote a cpp file including some classes. When I test it in a single file, everything works but when I link it with other c files, the data I stored in the array in the class changed. I know there must be something wrong with my memory allocation so I changed it into dynamic one using new 
but cant figure out where or how to fix

```
work in single .cpp file
```

```cpp
in a file called test.app
class Board
{
public:
    int **grid;
    bool done;
    int result;

public:
    Board()
    {
      grid = new int*[3];
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        grid[i] = new int[3];
      }
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        done=false;
        result=0;
    }
}

class Node
{

public:
    Board **arr;
    //double heuristic;
    bool done;
    int result;
    int prevx, prevy;
    int next_turn;

public:

    Node()

    {
       arr = new Board*[3];
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
         arr[i] = new Board[3];
       }
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = new Board();
            }
        }
        done = false;
        //heuristic=0;
        result = 0;
        prevx = -1;
        prevy = -1;
        next_turn=1;
    }
}
```

and the code where thing go wrong:

```
Treenode *head; //treat as global variable

void agent_start( int this_player )
{
  //nothing to do
  //cout << "here all good" << endl;
  head = new Treenode();
  //cout << head << endl;
  m = 0;
  return;

}

int agent_second_move( int board_num, int prev_move )
{
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {

      if(head->arr[res_boardx][res_boardy].grid[cordx][cordy] == 1)
      {
        cout << "here cant print" << endl;
        head->move2(i,j,-1);
        cout << "here cant print" << endl;
      }
      else if(head->arr[res_boardx][res_boardy].grid[cordx][cordy] == -1)
      {
        cout << "here cant print" << endl;
        head->move2(i,j,1);
      }
    }
  }
```

```
in test.h
extern int   port;
extern char *host;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  extern char *host;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  //  parse command-line arguments
  void agent_parse_args( int argc, char *argv[] );

  //  called at the beginning of a series of games
  void agent_init();

  //  called at the beginning of each game
  void agent_start( int this_player );

  int  agent_second_move(int board_num, int prev_move );

  int  agent_third_move(int board_num,int first_move,int prev_move);

  int  agent_next_move( int prev_move );

  void agent_last_move( int prev_move );

  //  called at the end of each game
  void agent_gameover( int result, int cause );

  //  called at the end of the series of games
  void agent_cleanup();
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
```

```
in main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    agent_start(1);
    int b = agent_second_move(1,1);
}
```

the output is:

```
[1]    26904 illegal hardware instruction
```

or

```
segmentation fault
```

before when I delared

```
class Node
{

public:
    Board arr[3][3]; ///
```

in Node class.

the working version before which caused data in treenode changed

```
class Board
{
public:
    int grid[3][3];
    bool done;
    int result;

public:
    Board()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        done=false;
        result=0;
    }
}
class Node
{

public:
    Board arr[3][3];
    //double heuristic;
    bool done;
    int grid[3][3];
    int result;
    int prevx, prevy;
    int next_turn;

public:

    Node()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = Board();
                grid[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        done = false;
        //heuristic=0;
        result = 0;
        prevx = -1;
        prevy = -1;
        next_turn=1;
    }
}

Treenode *head;
head = new Treenode();

void print_map(){
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
      int res_boardx, res_boardy, cordx, cordy;
      res_boardx = (i-1)/3;
      res_boardy = (i-1)%3;
      cordx = (j-1)/3;
      cordy = (j-1)%3;
      cout << head->arr[res_boardx][res_boardy].grid[cordx][cordy];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

the 2D array printed out is below when I call print function outside this
file which is wrong since it should either be 1 or 0 or -1.

```
433000000
107312758200000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
00000-1000
000000000
000000000
```

Comment: Please create proper [mcve]. This doesn't compile.

Comment: `arr[i][j] = new Board();` should give you at least a warning.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory le**a**k?

Comment: arr[i][j] = new Board() compiles fine without warning.

Comment: because the version before when I am not using dynamic memory allocation I declared everything array without pointer and new that works but the data stored in array changed between functions then i switch to dynamic allocation using new

Comment: How is `Treenode` related to `Board` and `Node`? What are `res_boardx`, `res_boardy`, `cordx`, and `cordy`? Are they also globals?

Comment: @ZihanQiu The only situation where `arr[i][j] = new Board()` would compile is if you have defined a converting constructor from `Board*` to `Board`.

Comment: res_boardx, res_boardy, cordx, and cordy can be treated as index which loop through grid

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the rule of 5. You have some memory allocation in constructor, so you need a non default destructor, to correctly free everything, as long as explicit move/copy constructors and assignment operators.

If possible, you should stick to standard containers like `std::vector` which handle all the corner cases for you.

Comment: shouldn't it because of I did not delete the memory since it should not be deleted at the current step.